# button changing its color

Tags: jquery, button, colors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>moockup< /title>
        <style>
            .yellowBackground {
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            .redBackground {
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="button" class="yellowBackground" id="thumb" >paina tästä< /button>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#button").click(function() {
                    changeThumb();
                });
            });
            function changeThumb() {
                $("#thumb").toggleClass("yellowBackground redBackground");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why that's not working i want to press that button and it must change its color to yellow and red after every click, i know how to do it in javascript but i am learning now jQuery.

Comment: you have two ids in your button tag....

Comment: aha i cant do that ? ok what i have to do now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution man : http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/9psL0oa0/

```
<button class="yellowBackground" id="thumb" >test</button>
```

css

```
.yellowBackground {

background-color: yellow;
}

.redBackground {

background-color: red;
}
```

js

```
$("#thumb").click(function() {

   $("#thumb").toggleClass("redBackground");

});
```

Comment: the toggleClass method thakes the classname that you want to add and remove... you assign a class by default and the toggle class should overwrite the default class

Comment: you should have only one ID attribute per tag, and it should be unique across the whole document

Comment: thank you Leo Javier !! so if i have for example <table> do i have to use one id in one row ? and can i use many classes ?

Comment: you should use classes... as long as you want many elements with the same behavior... for example $(".thumb")

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will answer your question.
fiddle[http://jsfiddle.net/57vss22x/3/]

jquery

```
$(".place").click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("green");
});
```

css

```
.place { background-color: yellow; }
.place.green { background-color: red; }
```

HTML

```
<button id="button" class="place" id="thumb" >paina tästä</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple id attribute in an element.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  changeThumb();
});
function changeThumb() {
  $("#button").toggleClass("yellowBackground redBackground");
}
```

```css
.yellowBackground {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.redBackground {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button" class="yellowBackground">paina tästä</button>
```